# Is it possible to override default aggregation for a column from Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm working on the custom extension. In our dataset there are columns for which "average" is the only aggregation that makes sense. However in Power BI Desktop all numeric columns get "sum" as a default aggregation. Can this be overridden from Power Query (e.g. type metadata)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to override this.

Comment: I've just created idea in the feedback service.
https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19765243-specify-default-aggregation-for-a-column-in-power

Answer (score 2):

For any field which is numeric and has a sigma, highlight the field in the field list and on the Modeling ribbon set the "Default Summarization" to the correct aggregation - in your case "Average".  The next time you drag it into a visual, it will use this aggregation.